# The extremal points of the dual polytopes of vertex transitive polytopes

Tags: convex-analysis, polytopes, convex-geometry, dual-cone

Is the following true? I have a convex polytope $P$ that is vertex transitive - roughly speaking all extremal points of $P$ have the same face-sets (the polytopes are isogonal figures). It is known that all convex polytopes have at least minus faces, where minus-faces are faces with dimension $\mathsf{dim}(P)-1$. Are the extremal points of the dual polytope $P^*$ all correspond to linear functionals that are supporting hyperplanes of the minus-faces of $P$?

To give an intuition for this, if you take a vertex transitive polytope in 3 dimensions (for example a Platonic solid), the extremal points of the dual polytope correspond to the 2-dimensional faces. I want to know if this is true in general for vertex transitive polytopes.

Comment: I do not see your question. Do you want to ask whether your last sentence is true?

Comment: Yes, thank you for clarifying. I want to ask if it the last sentence is true.

Comment: Isn't your question true for *all* (bounded) polytopes? A polytope can be written as an intersection of finitely many halfspaces. The normal vectors of these halfspaces are precisely the vertices of the dual polytope and the intersection of each halfspace with your original polytope is a 'minus face'. Do I miss something?

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was thinking. However, if you take for example the cone generated by a pentagon, then this cone is strongly self-dual. So the extremal rays of the dual cone correspond to the extremal rays of the original cone. The dual cone extremal rays give the cone generated by the dual polytope (I believe?). So Im worried that I'm missing something / some mathematical subtlety here - as here it appears the dual polytope actually corresponds directly to the original polytope (when we construct it in this way, which I believe is the rigorous way to do it)